# How to make async/await actually wait

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, fetch, slack

I am new to Node JS and trying to build a simple Slack slash command that looks up a query in a glossary in Google sheets.

I am struggling to understand how to properly handle async/await. And seem to end up with a Promise Pending or no results at all when I run `response = validateImages(response);`. I need the program to wait until the images are validated before continuing, but no matter how I write it I can't seem to make the script actually wait.

What would be the correct way of calling `validateImages(response)`?

**My main function looks like this:**

```js
// Gets a request object from Slack
app.post('/', (req, res) => {

  const query = req.body.text;
  let response = [];
  
  // Kills request if it cannot be verified
  slack.verifyWebhook(req);
    
  // Acknowledges request to Slack
  slack.ack(req, res);

  // Run query on google sheet and return a list of results
  response = glossary.getGlossaryResult(query); //To be implemented
  
  // Validate images in response - and delete any invalid images
  response = validateImages(response); 
  
  // Format the response for slack to meet Slack's 3000ms requirement (shorturl.at/bzDY5)
  response = slackBlockFormat(response);
  
  // Reply back to Slack on req.body.response_url
  slack.reply(req, response);
});
```

**And the validateImages() looks like this:**

```js
// Checks if each of the image URLs are valid. If they are not, delete the image from the result.
const validateImages = async(results) => {

  for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    try {

      // Tests the url
      const res = await fetch(results[i].image.contentUrl;, {method: 'HEAD'});

      // If not valid, delete
      if (!res.status == 200) {
        delete results[i].image.contentUrl;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  //Returns the updated results array
  return results;
};
```

After hours on hours of tutorials, rewrites, Googling, promises, resolves, and hair pulling, I got the code working using this package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-exist-sync), but it feels a bit like cheating, and I would love to fundamentally understand the async/await concept.

I would be very grateful to get some help with this!

Comment: A simple "await" in front of the call validateImages() should solve the problem. The await keyword just means to wait until the promise resolves; I.E. wait for your asynchronous function to finish and return its result.

Comment: Thanks @UnsignedByte. When I add await in front of the call, the script seems to end without any other things happening.

I tried:
`response = await validateimages(response);` then `console.log(response);`. Nothing is logged to the console. If I comment out `response = await validateimages(response);`, I can print the response object no problem.

Not sure if this gives a clue..?

Comment: Try printing results from inside validateImages? My guess is that validateImages isn't returning what you want it to. The async function will return a promise regardless, but this means when the promise resolves it returns undefined.